# Javascript prototype function failure

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I'm playing with prototype functions and can't understand why the simple example below isn't returning the negative of a number.

```
Number.prototype.neg = function(x) { return -x };

var num = -1;
var num2 = 1234;

console.log(num.neg());   // returns NaN (and not 1)
console.log(num2.neg());  // returns NaN (and not -1234);
```

Any idea where I've made the mistake?  I know that I could use property getters instead, but I'm working my way through the basics first (and hopefully learning from the mistakes).

Comment: Seriously? Someone voted that down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing any parameter to the function, so according to how you declared the function, you need to do:

```
num.neg(-1);
```

Returning -x when x is undefined gives you `NaN`. But that kind of defeats the purpose. You need to declare the function a bit differently:

```
Number.prototype.neg = function() { return -this };
```

Comment: To whoever's hiding behind the downvote, please explain your action.

Comment: Thanks Omri.  Really obvious once it's pointed it.  I'm now referring to -this with no arguments and it works fine.